# Why does removing shopware app crashes shop?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I'm developing a shopware 6 app and there is a strange behaviour when uninstalling and removing the app it appears, that the whole shop crashes, because it is still looking for the directory in the custom/apps folder. After uploading it manually via sftp the shop is reachable again. How can this happen?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How did you remove the app? And did you try running a `bin/console cache:clear` after removing it? As some files might still be referenced from the cache.

If you remove the app from the `My Extension` listing or use the `bin/console app:deactivate YourAppName` before deleting the files the issue should go away.

Comment: I should mention that the shop version is 6.4.20.0 and I only used the UI to first uninstall and afterwards remove the extension. I am testing use cases for possible future customers and there is no way that my app crashes the shop because of standard usage of the shops own ui. In addition I can't expect my customers to run console commands.